# Django filter on multiple array list values

Tags: python, django

I have to do a filter according to 3 fields: `Doctor`, `Client` and `Branch`. Each one of them is an array of ids, so I want to filter by these ids.

My django view code:

```
my_dict = {
    'BranchId': [0,1,2,4],
    'DoctorId': [2,4,5],
    'ClientId': [2,3,5],
}

Branches = my_dict['BranchId']
Doctors = my_dict['DoctorId']
Clients = my_dict['ClientId']

query = Event.objects.all().filter(
    e_d__in=Doctors,
    e_b__in=Branches,
    e_c__in=Clients)
print(query)
```

Comment: Does this not work? What error do you get?

Comment: @Boutros what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ralf i want to know how it works if i have 3 arrays

Comment: It's doesn't matter how many arrays you have. This filtering is almost similar to the [**`IN` operation in SQL**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what your question is exactly, but I'll try to explain the concept of the query.

If you use the [field lookup `__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) in a queryset, the value of your field has to be one of the values present in the list you provide.

Here is a reduced version of your code (it has the same functionality, but with more explicit names and less lines of code).

```
my_dict = {
    'branch_id_list': [0, 1, 2, 4],
    'doctor_id_list': [2, 4, 5],
    'client_id_list': [2, 3, 5],
}
query = Event.objects.filter(
    e_d__in=my_dict['branch_id_list'],
    e_b__in=my_dict['doctor_id_list'],
    e_c__in=my_dict['client_id_list'])
print(query)
```

This code expects that your model `Event` has the 3 fields `e_a`, `e_b` and `e_c`; each of them has to be an `IntegerField` (or something similar that has an `int` as its base type).

The query will return all `Event` instances where the 3 conditions are met; that is, each of the 3 fields needs to have a value that is in there respective lists.

Does that answer your question?